# My son's screen time does not appear on one of my devices even though I can see his permission request from the device

Tags: ios, parental-controls

I have 6 iOS 15 devices, among them,

- 5 are using same apple id, as parent devices
- another one is using child apple id.

Previously parent controls worked well and child screen time were showed on all 5 parent devices.

However, after I did following things, one of my device can not show child screen time at all.

- all update to iOS15
- backup 1 parent device (let us call it OLD) and restore it to another device (let us call it NEW).

The result is that the NEW can not show child screen time, but can continue see child permission request from my son, I can still approve/reject, just can not show hist screen time from the NEW.

I have tried turn off family share then turn on again, rejoined my son's device into family, all other parent devices works as before, but just the NEW does not work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No worry, I found the answer. It is because of too many devices, maximum 5 devices in a family.

Actually I have another 7 devices, include a MacOS. After I factory reset the OLD, I still have 6 devices in total, 5 parent devices, 1 child device.

Since the Apple's family feature can only handle maximum 5 devices, so only 4 parent devices can see my son's screen time, the 5th(NEW) can not.

After I sign out Apple id from the MacOS (i.e, reduced total device count into 5, so all 4 parent devices including the NEW now can see my son's screen time).